# iptables: how to give an ip access to a tcp service for one hour?

Tags: linux, iptables, timeout

I would like to give an ip access to tcp port 3306 for an hour. After that, all connections must be closed.

How can i add a timeout to the following expression?

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --source 1.2.3.4 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe (I've never used it, and found it through the iptables man page) --timestart and --timestop will accomplish this.

`iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -m tcp -p tcp --source 1.2.3.4 --dport 3306 --timestart 13:00 --timestop 14:00 -j ACCEPT`

Would allow you between 1 and 2pm.

> This matches if the packet arrival time/date is within a given range.
> All options are facultative.
>
> **--timestart** *value*
>
> Match only if it is after 'value' (Inclusive,
> format: HH:MM ; default 00:00).
>
> **--timestop** *value*
>
> Match only if it is before 'value' (Inclusive,
> format: HH:MM ; default 23:59).

Comment: Will this terminate established connections (which is what I believe JMW is asking for)?

Comment: active connections do not get disconnected, but this is working: ``iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -m tcp -p tcp --source 1.2.3.4 --dport 3306 --timestart 13:00 --timestop 14:00 -j ACCEPT``

Comment: @JMW Thanks, I updated my answer to include your edit.

Comment: Depending on what rules are already in firewall this will probably not work since you use append rule (-A)

Comment: if you wanted to terminate connections; you could add an explicit `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` for all connections falling outside of the time slot

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution that does not require iptables time module supported.

```
( iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT ; sleep 1h; iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT ) &
```

This won't close the connections after hour, it will simply return to whatever policy was before allowing the connection; which can be setup to interrupt and drop/reject the no longer allowed traffic unless you have STATE ESTABLISHED ALLOW beforehand.